# Google Chrome extension to archive a web page

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can archive a web page. I am currently using  [Wayback Machine](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wayback-machine/fpnmgdkabkmnadcjpehmlllkndpkmiak/reviews?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog), however  from time to time Wayback Machine servers are down, thereby preventing the user from archiving a page, so I am looking for an alternative solution (using another archive service that is likely to still exist for a while). Any license, price and operating system is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [PageArchiver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagearchiver/ihkkeoeinpbomhnpkmmkpggkaefincbn?hl=en) extension. It can sort through archives by date, content, size, and much more. It's easy to use and has features for editing archives and attaching notes. It has a rating of 3.5/5, which is good enough for most people to use.